# Walker Class - Check if menu item has description and if so add class to li

Tags: menus, walker

I am using a pretty common walker class to pull in the description when I call the `wp_nav_menu` function. I am using this to add an optional second line for the menu, using the description. This of course makes the menu items uneven, if some have descriptions and some don't. I've come down to two possibilities:

1. Within the custom walker class, check to see if a menu item has a description and if so, add a unique class to the parent `li` on that menu item only.
2. Use css to vertically center the anchor text within the li if it has the span (description) or not

Anyone know of either solution, or another one?

Walker Class being used:

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a class="has-description"'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '<span>' . $item->description . '</span>';
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, if i'm not mistaken you simply want to have an extra class for the `li` if the description is not empty?